# Pass "value" variable from "input button" to php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form in html with a

```
<input type="button" id="mainbutton" name="button1" value="usd"/>
```

Now when I click "submit" button, it posts to "/php/calculate.php".
There I would like to "get" the value from the "button1", which is usd.
That value doesnt seem to get passed over to the php script tho..
Any idea how to solve that?

Here the form: (value of "input type text" does get passed to "calculate.php", but not value from input type button)

```
<form class="calculator" action="php/calculate.php" method="post" id="profitForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">                             
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="neogasamount" placeholder="Amount">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="neogasprice" placeholder="Buying Price in $">


<input type="button" id="mainbutton" name="button1" value="usd"/>

 <input type="submit" id="profitsubmit" style="margin-top:10px;" class="btn btn-primary" value="Calculate Profit">
 </form>
```

thanks!

Comment: can you provide your php script?

Comment: add your php code to the post

Comment: Which button are you clicking to submit the form?  Only the value of the clicked button would be sent by the browser.

Comment: Why you set value to button, instead use hidden field

Answer (score 0):

The value of button1 isn't transmitted because you submit with the input type="submit". Add input type="hidden" to your form or use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do here is have a button that lets the user choose the type of currency and send that along with the form. Something like a select box or radio button would be better for that, but if you really truly want to use `<button>`, you could add `onclick="setCurrency()"` to the button, and then write a `setCurrency()` function that sets a hidden field within the form to the desired value, and that field's value would get sent to php when you POST.

Comment: Thats exactly what it is. When "toggling" the button you can choose from 2 currencies. If USD is chosen, the value is usd. If EUR is chose, the value is eur.  Now I would need to pass these values. Where do I need to add "onclick="setCurrency()"" and what kind of function would I need to write? Thanks alot!

Comment: Ah hey :) i've solved it. On button click, it does now also change value of a "hidden" input. :)